# Python add list of objects as dict value

Tags: python, dictionary

everybody!
I think it is very simple, but I have no idea how to do that.
I have an dict:

```
 message = {'message': 'bla bla bla', 'data':[]}
```

and a list:

```
 my_list = [('a', 1), ('b', 2)]
```

I want to append data from the list to the dict. My dict eventually should be:

```
 {'message': 'bla bla bla', 'data':[{'text': 'a', 'value': 1}, {'text': 'b', 'value': 2} ]}
```

I tried to do something like that:

```
 for item in my_list:
      message['data'][array.index(item)] = {'text': item[0], 'value': item[1]}
```

but it's not working :(

Comment: Where did `array` come from? Just use `message['data'].append({'text': item[0], 'value': item[1]})`. (Note that `dict(zip(("text", "value"), item))` will also work to create the desired `dict`.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this in one simple line:

```
message['data'].extend({'text': t, 'value': n} for t, n in my_list)
```

The generator expression creates a sequence of the desired `dict` values, and `extend` appends them to `message['data']` one at a time.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```py
for item in my_list:
    message['data'] += [{'text': item[0], 'value': item[1]}]
```

It appends the item to the message['data'] list by using python's `+` operator for lists.

The reason your code doesn't work is because you're trying to access an item in `message['data']` which is an empty list.